# Evaluate the inverse Laplace transform using convolution theorem where the argument is a function of s

Tags: laplace-transform

We have from convolution theorem:

> If $H(s)=F(s)G(s)$ then $$h(t)=L^{-1}\{F(s)G(s)\}=\int_{u=0}^t f(t-u)g(u)du$$

Here, I want to know if $$H(s)=F(P(s))G(P(s))$$ where $P(s)$ is a function of $s$, then the inverse of $H(s) $ i.e $h(t)$ will be..........?

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can only write to this:

$h(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t}\{F(P(s))G(P(s))\}=\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t}\{F(P(s))\}*\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t}\{G(P(s))\}=\int_0^t\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t-u}\{F(P(s))\}*\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to u}\{G(P(s))\}~du=\int_0^t\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to u}\{F(P(s))\}*\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t-u}\{G(P(s))\}~du$

Note that Laplace transform has not any composite function rules.